# Winform App freezes when apply Application.EnableVisualStyles()

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging, crash

My Application has been frozen at a point  when It contains `Application.EnableVisualStyles()` in Programs.cs.

First running is ok. but When I change format Datetime  of Windows from `"DD/MM/YYYY"`  to others format
Application  has been frozen.

I have tried hidding `Application.EnableVisualStyles()` and it works right.
But the GUI of Form has been changed

I want to keep Visual style, please can you help me the best solution.

Here is my main function.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
           AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
           Application.ThreadException += new System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
            if (IsProcessOpen("CMSServerSetting"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("CMS Server Setting is running", "Notification", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                Environment.Exit(1);
            }
            Application.EnableVisualStyles(); // When it's hidden, Application works right
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.DoEvents();

            Application.Run(new CMSSettingForm());
        }
```

Comment: What OS are you trying to run this on?

Comment: Crashed! Well, What's the exception? post stacktrace too

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Notice in the body of his question he never said "crashed" only "frozen". Thus I edited the title to say "freezes" instead of "crashed".

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I commented before your edit. that was misleading!

Comment: exactly it has been  frozen on Release build and not in debug.